# Apparent subject change in a sentence with ながら

Tags: grammar, parsing

I've come across this bit of dialogue in a visual novel (*Easter Night* from *Ensemble Stars!*):

> A 「『イースターナイト』衣装も見られたので、私はそこそこ満足ですよ？」
> B 「**手品を披露しながら言われても**馬鹿にされてる気分にしかならないのだよ」
> A 「すみませんね〜 職業病なものでっ♪」

For context, the outfit mentioned is one that B had created for himself despite still recovering from a crisis.

The way the bolded phrase makes sense to me, it's B complaining about A showing off his magic tricks while talking to him, which makes him feel ridiculed. However wouldn't that mean there's subject change between the 手品を披露し and 言われても, something ungrammatical, as [this lesson](https://www.imabi.net/theparticlenagara.htm) on IMABI seems to say (first paragraph under *Simultaneous Action*)?

Interpreting the sentence in a way that unifies the subjects would mean either that 1. B is doing the tricks, which doesn't fit the character (much less than A and his entertainer's 職業病, anyway), or that 2. A is the one being spoken to (言われても), but in that case the exchange doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Is that really an error, or am I missing something about either the verbs used or the parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. It means *I feel just ridiculed if you talk while doing a magic.*

A way to make sense of this is, to think that the verb phrase 手品を披露しながら言う as a whole is turned into the passive form 手品を披露しながら言わ + れる, rather than 手品をしながら + 言われる.

Practically XしながらYされる always follows this pattern, as far as I can think of. That is, X is done by the doer of Y.

---

If X and Y are both something done to the speaker, X is appended by (ら)れる. For example,

- 頭をつかま**れ**ながら殴られる held by the head and beaten